# Probabilistic interpretation of Fourier Transform

Tags: probability, fourier-transform

The fourier transform is given as below :

$$F(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t) e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d}t$$

Now $$F(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t) e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d}t$$ can be transformed as

$$F(\omega) = 0.5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} k s(k) e^{-i \omega k^2} \mathrm{d}k$$

where $ k = \sqrt{t} $
and $ s(k) = f(t^2) $

The exponential term inside the integral looks like a gaussian distribution although it is a complex function.  Is there any connecting probabilistic interpretation along these lines of the fourier transform or series ? Under such an idea a fourier transform would be an expectation of a gaussianish distribution.

Looking forward to insights.

Comment: The square or square root functions are not bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so your variable limits don't make sense.

Comment: @aschepler : I understand , I was just wondering if there exists an idea which is somewhat similar to this , with the corner cases taken care of .

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function of a real-valued random variable $X$ is given by

$$\varphi_X (t):=E[e^{itX}],$$

which is an object that completely characterizes the distribution of $X$. If $X$ admits a density function $f$, then $\varphi_X(-t)$ is the Fourier transform of its density function (modulo any differences in a normalizing constant or sign conventions).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is interesting to know. I did not know about this . :) I believe , if I read more on it I would discover some connections , but does this idea anyway lead to viewing this as a combination of gaussians(of some sort) ?

Comment: @mathiasglaser The above is general; it applies for any random variable. Perhaps you are reminded of the Gaussian distribution because of the exponential function, but I don't think there's much more connection than that.  One nice property is that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function is another Gaussian function, as seen [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html).

Comment: But , is there any idea in which , any fourier transform,  can be seen as an expectation under some kind of gaussians ?

Comment: Sorry , had not seen your comment before my last comment

Comment: @mathiasglaser Not that I immediately see; the change of variables in your question is incorrect as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Is it incorrect because it lacks bijectivity ?

Comment: @mathiasglaser Yes; what would be the corresponding $k$ bound for $t=-\infty$?

Comment: Well , was not trying to exactly establish anything rigoroulsy , just was following an intuition and trying to find if any concept exists which is along these lines